# Is the ball ratio theorem for Radon–Nikodým derivative known for general metric spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

Given two non-negative Borel measures $\mu$, $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, that are finite on compact sets, such that $\nu\ll\mu$, it is well known that

$$\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x)= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\nu(B_\epsilon(x))}{\mu(B_\epsilon(x))}$$

holds $\mu$ a.e., where $B_\epsilon(x)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Can this be generalized to measures on arbitrary metric spaces, or even Banach spaces?

I am particularly interested in the case of probability measures (for which the quantities in the above fraction are finite). Additionally, if necessary, these could also be Radon.

Comment: see Theorem 1.8 in Heinonen - Lectures on analysis on metric spaces. It tells that if $\mu$ is "nice" with respect to the metric, and $\nu$ is "nice" with respect to $\mu$, then the property holds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arbitrary metric spaces, no.

A classic text discussing such "derivation" is:

*Hayes, C. A.; Pauc, C. Y.*, Derivation and martingales, Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. 49. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. VII, 203 p. (1970). [ZBL0192.40604](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0192.40604).

I think you get trouble even in $\mathbb R^2$ if you define your metric so that the $r$-ball centered at $(x,y)$ is something like
$$
[x-r,x+r] \times [y-e^{-1/r},y+e^{-1/r}]
$$

---

*plug*
This is covered in Chapter 7 of my text with Sucheston:

*Edgar, G. A.; Sucheston, Louis*, [**Stopping times and directed processes.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511574740), Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications 47. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-13508-5/pbk). xii, 428 p. (2010). [ZBL1189.60074](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1189.60074).

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'll have to think about that problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ a bit more.